# iPhone modal View with parent view semi-visible?

Tags: iphone, modal-dialog

I am adding a modal view using the following code:

`[self presentModalViewController:phrasesEditor animated:YES];`

How can I make the modal view semi-transparent so that the superview "shines" through?

My complete method/function looks like this:

```
-(IBAction)showEditPhrases:(id)sender{
    PhrasesViewController *phrasesEditor = [[PhrasesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PhrasesViewController" bundle:nil];
    phrasesEditor.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [phrasesEditor.view setAlpha: 0.5];
    [phrasesEditor.view setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]];
    [self presentModalViewController:phrasesEditor animated:YES];
    [phrasesEditor release];
}
```

EDIT:

The pragmatic approach of changing the alpha will not work, apparently. How can I load a NIB into a UIView and interact with it?

I have a UIViewController now. Do I convert/modify/change it into a UIVIew and then load it, or am I supposed to do something else?

EDIT 2:

I tried `[self.view addSubview:phrasesEditor.view];`, but that leaves me with no way to remove the subview. Each view seems to have its own View Controller.

EDIT 3:

I thought that I should mention that the superview is inside of a view controller called iDecideViewController and the phrasesEditor has a separate View Controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you present a modal view it will actually unload the previous view so that is not what you want at all. UIView has a method called addSubview which will put the new view on top of its siblings.

Instead of:

```
[self presentModalViewController:phrasesEditor animated:YES];
```

do:

```
[self.view addSubview:phrasesEditor.view];
```

This is assuming you are already in a ViewController subclass.

Comment: removeFromSuperview on phrasesEditor.view

Comment: I'm not sure about that. It has a separate View Controller from phrases editor and causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: EDIT: I figured it out. I was `[phraseEditor release]` ing too early.

Comment: So now I'm leaking memory, gotta take of that.

Comment: Taken care of. I've decided to stick with `[self presentModalViewController:phrasesEditor animated:YES];` and apply a background image to that via UIImage. Problems solved.

Answer (score 1):

I Had the same problem and added a property and 2 methods to a subclass of UIViewController to mimic the behavior of presentModalViewController:animated:

For mor information, see my blog post: [How to display a transparent modal view controller](http://www.cocoaosx.com/2011/10/20/how-to-display-transparent-modal-viewcontrollers/) or check out the code below:

```
#pragma mark - Transparent Modal View
-(void) presentTransparentModalViewController: (UIViewController *) aViewController 
                                     animated: (BOOL) isAnimated 
                                    withAlpha: (CGFloat) anAlpha{

    self.transparentModalViewController = aViewController;
    UIView *view = aViewController.view;

    view.opaque = NO;
    view.alpha = anAlpha;
    [view.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        UIView *each = obj;
        each.opaque = NO;
        each.alpha = anAlpha;
    }];

    if (isAnimated) {
        //Animated
        CGRect mainrect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(0, mainrect.size.height, mainrect.size.width, mainrect.size.height);


        [self.view addSubview:view];
        view.frame = newRect;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.8
                         animations:^{
                             view.frame = mainrect;
                         } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             //nop
                         }];

    }else{
        view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        [self.view addSubview:view];
    }






}

-(void) dismissTransparentModalViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL) animated{

    if (animated) {
        CGRect mainrect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(0, mainrect.size.height, mainrect.size.width, mainrect.size.height);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.8
                         animations:^{
                             self.transparentModalViewController.view.frame = newRect;
                         } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             [self.transparentModalViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
                             self.transparentModalViewController = nil;
                         }];
    }


}
```